# what is the right scenario to pitch you game to the publisher?

Tags: publishing

right now im cooperating with a team to prepare a demo to get sponsored by a publisher.

based on articles i read there are many factors and scores that based on them the publisher decides to support the game or not.

- knowing the goal maket and group of people you make them the game.
- platform
- how much fun it is and how much it can take people attention.
- how much of the game is made
- experience of the team in the industry
- good plan and scheduling
- ...

i know they consider all of these factors. the problem is when a team contitnues working when the team is paid and also receive good feedbacks from buplisher, the process will be more ontime and less parts of the game will be moved to garbage.

my main question is when is the earliest time that the team can present the product to the publisher and be hopefull that can get support by them with lowest risk. i mean most of the time is a demo or prototype enough to start talking with them or its important to have the game mostly finished to get their support and feedback?

Comment: What is the track record of your team and how big is the publisher you aim for?

Comment: FWIW Many years ago, I worked at a place where we had a demo for a game we hoped to complete and release, then when we met publishers, instead of greenlighting out game, they had us work as a "white label" on some other games they needed help to release. After a few games working with them, we eventually managed to release our own games. Maybe the demo we had was a proof that we knew a bit how to program the games, and they provided us with what the market was expecting... (I was not involved with interaction with the publishers.)

Comment: @Zibelas all team members have at least 1_2 game titles and any good publisher that is good with pc indie games is welcome.